# Extension Host Terminated Unexpectedly (vs code) Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been struggling with this vs code issue (extension host terminated unexpectedly).

I've tried uninstalling/ reinstalling vs code, I've uninstalled and disabled all my extensions and still get the error, I've downloaded an older version which worked temporarily, I'm out of ideas.

I don't understand how I can have no extensions but the still get the error?
does anybody know the answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

it seems I'm having the same issue as your from around the same time. I would suggest to add **more infos**, in my case for example

```
> MacOS X : 10.11.6 El Capitan
> VS Code Version: 1.57.1
> Commit: 507ce72a4466fbb27b715c3722558bb15afa9f48
> Date: 2021-06-17T13:28:32.912Z
> Electron: 12.0.7
> Chrome: 89.0.4389.128
> Node.js: 14.16.0
> V8: 8.9.255.25-electron.0
> OS: Darwin x64 15.6.0
```

After a long period of not using VS Code I found this alert always popping up

```
-Extension host terminated unexpectedly
                -Open Developer Tools   -Restart Extension Host
```

And restarting just repeated this alert.
If I choose from the `context menu` (aka right click) `Run a line/selection` or `Run Current File`, either on terminal or in interactive window with Jupyter, it has no reaction (while a couple of days ago it worked perfectly, *when I used it in offline cause there was no wifi*)

---

---

***In hope it could help you, here are what I tried:***

- to deactivate and reactivate the extension (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> > Reload With
  Extensions disabled)
- to install a previous extension of Python ms-python.python (or whatever suit your case)
- to run the command Bisect (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> > Help: Start Extension
  Bisect)

So far I found no solution for me.

Soon I will try to follow what [sumitparakh commented in this github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95036) , meaning to save the former `extensionHostProcess.js` file (renaming it) and adding in its stead the file he provided

On Windows the location should be

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js
```

While MacOS path should be:

```
'/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js'
```

---

---

UPDATE 1: after adding the file and reloading I get *even* this message

```
-Your Code installation appears to be corrupt. Please Reinstall
                                           -More information
```

---

---

UPDATE 2: I tried to follow this [fix from a github issue](https://gist.github.com/sumitparakh/696472f8ebb164bc0e31d6b5529cab61) . Here is the quote:

> ehamwey commented on Jan 4
>
> The following steps worked for me, after upgrading from an x86 build
> of vscode-insiders to Darwin arm64 (version 1.53.0-insider) I got the
> behavior described above.
>
> ```
> Remove the folder: /Users/[your-home-folder]/.vscode/     # **NOTE:** I renamed it as a backup
> This will remove all extensions and any vscode configurations from your system!
> Reinstall vscode and any extensions
> ```

BUT, even after I reinstalled the same version 1.57.1 of Code the extension host error is there, *without* any extension yet installed...
So maybe, I should try to revert to a previous update and maybe even reporting this issue

**I'm open to suggestion aswell**

Answer (score 1):

I solved it running in the notebook kernel:

```py
pip install six
```